# Is it advisable to have 2 log4js running in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, logging, log4js-node

Is it advisable to have 2 log4js logging in my nodejs application.

Logger A (The standard logger) to file A:

- Print out / Info
- Error
- Warning

Logger B (Performance logger) to file B:

- Logs only performance (i.e. time taken to complete this transaction)

Both logger logging to 2 different files.

Answer (score 0):

I would integrate it only once and implement the following logic:

In Code use

```
logger.debug('Performance info');
logger.info('Print out / Info');
logger.warn('Warning');
logger.error('Error');
```

- In development mode: set the logger level to `debug`
- In staging/test mode if any: set the logger level to `info`
- In production mode: set the logger level to `warn`

Comment: What if i need to logged to 2 different files?

Comment: As in https://log4js-node.github.io/log4js-node/logLevelFilter.html use can configure multiple appenders to point to different log files and additionally  some appenders of type `logLevelFilter` with `level` (and `maxLevel`) to filter/pipe the logs to the appropriate target log files using only one logger  (the default category)